# Load a specific div on id base codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

[myiamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPFWE.png)

I have 2 forms as tab in signup page when one form is submit and if have any error I want to redirect to that specific tab which have error but did not happen.

Here is my view

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<section class="services">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="signup-wrapper well" style="margin-bottom: 80px; margin-top: 80px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="services__main">
                <h2 class="title title--main"><span class="title__bold">Sign Up</span><span class="line line--title"><span class="line__first"></span><span class="line__second"></span></span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="aside-tabs__links">
                <a href="#" class="no-decoration js-tab-link aside-tabs__active-link" data-for="#desc">Genrel User</a>
                <a href="#" class="no-decoration js-tab-link" data-for="#rev">Dealership</a>
            </div>
            <div class="aside-tabs__blocks about-tab js-tab-block no-b-border" id="desc" >
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <form action="<?= base_url();?>Home/add_user" method="post" >
                        <!-- class="quick-form"  -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Full Name" />
                        </div>
                        <?php echo form_error('fname'); ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        </div>
                        <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                        <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone #" />
                        </div>
                        <?php echo form_error('phone'); ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="select-2 form-control" name="city">
                                <option>Select City</option>
                                    <?php foreach ($results as $result) { ?>
                                        <option><?= $result->city; ?></option>
                                <?php   } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo form_error('city'); ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input  type="submit" class="btn button button--red button--main pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" value="Sign Up">
                        </div>
                    </form>                         
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="aside-tabs__blocks about-tab js-tab-block no-b-border" id="rev" style="display: none;">
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <form action="<?= base_url();?>Home/add_dealer" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <h4>Comapny Information</h4>
                        <hr>
                       <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cname" placeholder="Company Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="owner" placeholder="Owner Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="select-2 form-control" name="city">
                                <option>Select City</option>
                                    <?php foreach ($results as $result) { ?>
                                        <option><?= $result->city; ?></option>
                                <?php   } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Office Location" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Office Phone" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select name="business-type" class="form-control">
                                <option class="form-group">Products Deal</option>
                                <option class="form-group">Bikes</option>
                                <option class="form-group">Accessories</option>
                                <option class="form-group">Both</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="link" placeholder="social-link(optional)" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="button button--custom--grey button--main btn" id="logo">Upload Logo</button>

                            <input type="file" class="form-control hidden" id="logo1" name="logo1" /><span id="mylogo">* Format must be jpg,jpeg or png</span>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo form_error('logo'); ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="descrp" placeholder="Description(optional)"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <h4>Primary Information</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn button button--red button--main pull-right" value="Sign Up">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
            </div>
           </section>

     <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

here is my controller

```
    function add_dealer()
     {
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES);
    $config['upload_path'] = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\devilbirds\images\uploads';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']     = '0';
        $config['max_width'] = '0';
        $config['max_height'] = '0';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = 'TRUE';
        $config['overwrite'] = 'FALSE';
        $config['wm_text'] = 'Deveil Birds';
        $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
        $config['wm_font_path'] = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\devilbirds/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf';
        $config['wm_font_size'] = '16';
        $config['wm_font_color'] = 'aabbcc';
        $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
        $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
        $config['wm_padding'] = '20';

         $this->load->library('upload', $config);
         $this->image_lib->watermark();
        $abc = $this->upload->do_upload('logo1');
          $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
         // var_dump($abc);exit();
          $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cname','CName','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('logo1','Logo1','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address','Address','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Phone','trim|is_unique[bd_dealer.phone]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('owner','Owner','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('descrp','Descrp','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('business-type','Business-type','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('link','Link','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|is_unique[bd_dealer.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|min_length[5]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trim');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
    {
        $data['error'] = $this->session->set_flashdata('errors');
        $this->load->view('pages/signup',$data);// this is the link which loads my view i dont get how to go load that specific div from this url  
    }
    else
    {
            $userData = array(
                'company' => $this->input->post('cname'),
                'logo' => $file_name,
                'location' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                'name' => $this->input->post('owner'),
                'description' => $this->input->post('descrp'),
                'business_type' => $this->input->post('business-type'),
                'social_link' => $this->input->post('link'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                'city' => $this->input->post('city'));
             $data = array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                'user_type' => '2');
            //var_dump($userData);exit();
            $this->Home_m->add_dealer($userData);
            $this->Home_m->users($data);
            redirect('Home/login'); 
    }
}
```

I have two functions for two different forms in tabs. let suppose if i post my dealer form and this form have any issue then it will redirect to the signup page and it shows the pre-active tab which is general user signup. i want to redirect to the div that contain the form or dealer signup. any help will be appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: **Follow these step**

Now when you submit the form 

**If you get any error in form then pass some value from controller to view and check that value you are getting in view if you then active that form div tab do this same in form tab 2..**

when page first open value will be empty check that value using `isset` and make one tab active.

Comment: is not there is a way to go to load the view of  specific id from controller ?

Comment: Just make div show and hide...when you get any error show that div and if not hide and same thing in other div also.but you need to pass the value from controller to view.

Comment: ok that is the real issue uopn which data i have to show whcih tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller when you get error do this.

**for form one error**

```
 $data['error'] = $this->session->set_flashdata('errors');
$data['div1'] = "div1";
    $this->load->view('pages/signup',$data);// this is the link which loads my view i dont get how to go load that specific div from this url ,i have pass div1 as parameter
```

**For form two error**

```
$data['error'] = $this->session->set_flashdata('errors');
$data['div2'] = "div2";
$this->load->view('pages/signup',$data);// this is the link which loads my view i dont get how to go load that specific div from this url ,i have pass div1 as parameter
```

**In your view page**

```
<script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               var div1 =  "<?php $div1; ?>";
               var div2 = "<?php $div2; ?>";
               if(div1=='' && div2==''){
                   $("#desc").show();
                   $("#rev").hide();
               }else if(div1=='div1' && div2==''){
                   $("#desc").show();
                   $("#rev").hide();
               }else if(div1=='' && div2=='div2'){
                   $("#desc").hide();
                   $("#rev").show();
               }
           })
           </script>
```

**div1**

```
<div class="aside-tabs__blocks about-tab js-tab-block no-b-border" id="desc">
```

**Div2**

```
<div class="aside-tabs__blocks about-tab js-tab-block no-b-border" id="rev">
```

**I hope it will help you.**

Comment: why u pass div 1 as a parameter?

Comment: you can pass any parameter and that parameter need to be grab in view

Comment: Unable to load the requested file: pages/signup/div2.php

Comment: var div1 =  "<?php $div1; ?>";
 this is null

Comment: actually when i redirect from my controller if(div1=='' && div2=='')
               {
                alert('this is in 1st if');
                   $("#desc").show();
                   $("#rev").hide();
               } this  if is run every time

Comment: yes this will run everytime whenever page load because it checking is done in document.ready..Thats why

Comment: so now how to get that specific tab ? if this 'if' runs every time

Comment: As i explain you when you want to enable div1 then pass div1 data to view and for div2 pass data div2 to view .you can manage that.

Comment: am saying i pass that div2 parameter to $data in where i load my view but in script this return nothing its null

Comment: please share me your full view and controller code. i will make for you.

Comment: my full view is posted here as well as the controller ,,, i just asking you when it redirects from controller the two var in script are empty